# Outlook is repeatedly asking for another user's password?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook 2016 with on-prem Exchange server.  One particular user is repeatedly getting popups from Outlook that are asking her to login as another user.  It's a generic login window, but only happens when Outlook is running.  To make it even stranger, the user it wants her to login as is someone that left the company months ago and no longer has an Active Directory account.

So far we've checked for shared calendars and have checked Credential Manager.  Nothing found in either of those places.

Comment: Have you gone into File > Account Settings > Account Settings to check if the account still exists on the user's client?

Comment: Or, you can also create a new profile. Besides, we can see if you've add additional mailbox to your profile. To check this, go to File > Account Settings > Account Settings. Double click your account and choose More Settings > Advanced tab.

Comment: Found the More Settings button inside the account.  There's an additional mailboxes group that contained the old user account.  No idea how that got set, but I removed it and presumably the issue will be resolved.  Waiting to see as the popups were fairly intermittent.

Comment: @BillDOe Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to File > Account Settings > Account Settings and check if the old account still exists on the user's client.